# How to get Bamboo Ink working on a not supported device?

Tags: thinkpad, pen, bamboo

I'm trying to get Bamboo Ink Pen working on my ThinkPad Yoga 14 20DM. It's not listed on the website as compatible device, unlike ThinkPad Yoga 260 and ThinkPad 370 which are. So I'm looking for a possible workaround in order to enable the touch gestures of my pen to be registered.

I imagine it would be possible to use it to an extent if I manage to add the appropriate vendor id to the list of compatible drivers in the Bamboo Ink Stylus' driver installation, but I cannot seem to find the driver in any format other than pre-packaged installer whose configuration I cannot access. I am hoping to find some .inf-like file with installation configuration.

Does anyone have any other ideas or alternative workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current drives and try the [Wacom Feel drivers](http://us.wacom.com/en/feeldriver/).  Some people have stated having success with unlisted devices.